# Fill & sign in Acrobat DC Pro like in Acrobat DC

Tags: pdf, digital-signature, acrobat-pro-dc

The usual instructions on [how to draw a signature](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/acrobat/how-to/fill-sign-pdf-forms-electronically.html) seem to apply to Acrobat DC, not Acrobat Pro DC. This is how it looks like:

[image]

But in Acrobat Pro DC this item doesn't exist:

[image]

So how do I fill & sign?

Comment: Considering Acrobat Pro has ALL of the features of Acrobat Standard it that means we are missing some information.  I can confirm that option does exist on my copy of Acrobat DC Pro.

Comment: I believe the signature stuff only exists for certain languages.  Which 'application language' do you have Acrobat set to use in the options? If it's not "English" (only), then if you set it to English (and restart Acrobat) do they show up?

Comment: It might be how the screenshot was taken, but I see several differences, between the two images.  One the screenshot where the option is missing, seems to have larger icons, this seems to indicate its running on hardware with a touchscreen.  I hate to be "that guy" but provide is the about dialogs for each installation minus any PII

Comment: Yes, it's English. The first image is taken randomly from the web. Can you give a screenshot that proves your claim to have Fill & Sign in the pro version?

Comment: What did the tool search bring up?

Comment: Just sub-tools of the second screenshot. Nothing about fill & sign.